# How does Angular make sure user input is not malicious?

Tags: javascript, angular, security, xss

So, I was following this tutorial on how to create a router in vanilla JS. Then the author specified it was just for the sake of understanding how things worked, but we would be better off using a framework like Angular or React for many reasons, on of them being that Angular sanitized user input before inserting it into our HTML.

My question is, since Angular is all frontend, which mechanism prevents a hacker from manipulating it into accepting his malicious code? Maybe Angular calls some backend API? Still that could be manipulated, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular filters and encodes any values used in its templates so that they remain secure regardless of the data inserted into them. See [Angular Security](https://angular.io/guide/security).

A user could send malicious data as input but if it's encoded correctly when output then it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can Validate form input for example like:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
      required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
      [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >

<div *ngIf="name.invalid && (name.dirty || name.touched)"
    class="alert alert-danger">

  <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
    Name is required.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.minlength">
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="name.errors.forbiddenName">
    Name cannot be Bob.
  </div>

</div>
```

But theoretically a malicious user could still sent a request to the api with some manipulated input. To prevent this, your API, your backend server needs to have validations as well on much as you can. If your API only accepts certain inputs, your app is at least "safe" against malicious user input.

Answer (score 0):

What you referer to is called DOM XSS or Template Injection. Angular like other javascript frameworks (and software in general) are not perfect. Angular parsing security has been breaked and fixed already. But usually is the application developer who make mistakes. A lot of times a code example is interpreted as a full featured pieze of software and copy pasted in multiple sources without any security tests.

Aarree response is totally wrong. XSS detection has to be ALSO at client side to avoid totally undetectable client side injections, mostly DOM ones, but also some mutation XSS or weird browser behaviour could be stoped at client side but no at server side. This is why some top tier security experts are working hard on projects like this: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify

For example if you are reading from hash urls (like js router does) there is possible a malicious injection if not well design or mistakes were made. Bastly common on innerHTML, templates, eval or html attributes ammong other sinks.

I made you a simple example you can test:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
eval(location.hash.substr(1))
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Just save it as xss.html and append #alert(1) to the url.
When you use #, the url is not send to the server, there is no way to detect this vulnerabilities server side because browsers strip the # and everything after in the addressbar from the request to the server.

In an example like this i could reply the login page at your website, and add a keylogger using javascript to send it after the #url to a legit user. He would trust the link and lose his account. In most cases can be done in 20 lines of javascript. And the url is easy to fake: [https://example.com/home/newFeature/login.php](https://example.com/home/newFeature/login.php#Malicous_Code_Goes_Here)

Answer (score -1):

so angular doesn't call backend api on its own. But i can imagine that it will regex-check for malicious code or do some magic like that. But if you want to have a real validation it should never be in the frontend.

Frontend validation should be used to help the user to fill in the right data. If you want validation for security and malicious code. it should happen in the backend.